# SELECT statement inside of INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I've got a table called `Log` with an column called `LogID` (data type `Integer`).

Whenever I want to write to this table I would like to add 1 to the `LogID`, as multiple threads access the `Log` table. I need to do this the second I insert the statement.

How do I get the value of `LogID`, add 1 to it and use it in the same statement to insert?

I have the following code:

```
INSERT INTO `Log` (`LogID`, `Date`, `Time`, `Server`, `Type`, `P`, `S`, `T`, `Log`) 
VALUES ("172350","2017-03-08", "15:15:15","X","X","X","X","X","X");
```

172350 is the `LogID`. I need to replace it with something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(`LogID`) FROM `Log` + 1
```

Comment: Why not you are giving this column as auto increment?

Comment: Have you tried to replace it?

Comment: Even running the SELECT "at the second" the INSERT is executed doesn't satisfactorily address the potential race condition... i.e. two sessions retrieving the same value for `MAX(LogID)`... not without adding some locking that kills concurrency. MySQL has already implemented a solution to your question: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: It's incredibly unlikely that this would ever be something that you would *need* to do. It's a terrible idea for a whole host of widely discussed reasons.